# Regex Match All Unless?

Tags: c#, regex, substring, regex-lookarounds

Assuming I want:

```
TESTGRID - NOT MATCH
testgrid - NOT MATCH
ACTIVEID - MATCH
activeID - MATCH
testRID - MATCH
```

I've tried:

```
(?!([^GR]))ID*?\b (I really thought I had it with this one - Don't match ID if it is preceeded with GR, right?
(?!([^GRID]))ID*?\b
(?!([GRID]))ID*?\b
```

None of which is working.

I swear I'm getting better with regex, though :)  I've managed to knock out the last 6 attempts without seeking help from SO, but I'm once again stuck :(

Comment: Did you mean `(?<!GR)ID\b`? Or do you need to match the whole *string* / *word*? Like `\w*(?<!GR)ID\b`?

Comment: Wiktor, that did it.  (?<!GR) is what I was missing.  I tried [^GR]ID*?\b, but as you can imagine, testRID was not matched.  I had the syntax for a string grouping incorrect, it appears.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Don't match ID if it is preceeded with GR

If you mean to match `ID` that is at the end of the word, and is not preceded with `GR`, use

```
(?<!GR)ID\b
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!GR)ID%5Cb&i=%20-%20NOT%20MATCH%0D%0ATESTGRID%0D%0Atestgrid%0D%0A%20-%20MATCH%0D%0AACTIVEID%0D%0AactiveID%0D%0AtestRID)

Note that `(?<!GR)` is a *negative lookbehind* that fails the match if the lookbehind pattern finds a match to the left of the current position in the string. If you use `[^GR]`, a negated character class, then only one single symbol/character is checked for (a character other than `G` and `R`), not a character *sequence*.

Comment: In this case, I just want the ID at the end of the word.  I was close, and you pointed out my error, so thank you :)  I'll accept in 8 more minutes lol.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant part and added a demo link.